# Naming parameters in generic Func delegates

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I'm creating an API that has a `reduce`-method, taking a `Func<in T, in T, out T>`. This can then be used as `reduce((prev, curr) => prev+curr)`. Fairly standard.

But...

I always have a hard time remembering - which parameter comes first? The accumulator or the current item?

Is there any way of giving some hint to the IDE so that when the codecompletion pops up, it can tell something different than `arg1` and `arg2` ?
Like the 'dreamed up' syntax `Func<in T as prev, in T as curr, out T>` or `Func<in prev:T, in curr:T, out T>`?

Or can I use some special comments that will be picked up by the code completion?

Comment: You don't have to write only `T`, you can name it like you want eg. `TPrev`, `TCurr`.

Comment: Rather than expecting a function you could create a definition of a delegate and put it as the parameter in your method signature. The consumer can user it by providing either a `Func` it actually newing up the delegate (no one should be doing that with modern C# versions). The point is, if you open the parenthesis you could see the parameters names in your delegate which would give the consumer some insight.

Comment: @RandRandom but this would not ensure TPrev to be the same as TCurr though?